# View error traceback when running commands from VS Code Python debugger

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

When I use the VS Code debugger with Python to stop at some breakpoints, I often write some lines straight in the debug console (use it as interactive Python shell within my program).

The problem is, when I have errors in these lines, when typed from the debug console, I don't see the full Python-style traceback of the error, but only the last line (<Error_type>: ), i.e., without references to code file where the error was raised, the line raised it, and the full stack trace.

Is there any way to configure the VS Code debugger to show the full traceback for errors raised by lines executed from the debugger?

I develop (and debug) on remote machine through ssh.

Example:

I wrote a file named tmp2.py, which contains:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, val):
        print(val)

a = A()
```

If I put debug point on line 5: `print('start')`,
and then from the debug console type directly `a = A()`, I see this one line output:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'val'
```

but if I run the full program I see the this elaborated output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/innereye/anaconda2/envs/py3tf2/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/innereye/anaconda2/envs/py3tf2/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/innereye/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.91350/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "/home/innereye/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.91350/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "/home/innereye/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.91350/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 267, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(options.target, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "/home/innereye/anaconda2/envs/py3tf2/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "/home/innereye/anaconda2/envs/py3tf2/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/home/innereye/anaconda2/envs/py3tf2/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/innereye/deeplearning/tmp2.py", line 6, in <module>
    a = A()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'val'
```

which directs me to the actual file and line where the error raises.

I want the debugger to show me the second output also for lines executed directly from the debug console.

Comment: But in the debug console, there is no line number from which the error originates. You just typed the line yourself. Beyond that I don't think there is any useful information in the stack trace. Everything you see in the strack trace except the last line are just multiple layers of wrappers which VS Code uses to eventually call a Python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it seems like impossible， VSCode hasn't provided related configuration. And I consider that's very hard to get what you want, this is because of the debug theory.